# Error CORS Forbidden 403 Spring Boot With Spring Security when using Path Variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

I know there already a lot of questions & answers about this topic, but none mention about this Error when using path variable.

I already put this config

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
   {
    http
     .cors().and()
     .csrf().disable()
     .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/file/getFile/**")           
        .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
     .and()
     .httpBasic();
   }
}
```

and when I use the path variable the response always error 403 Forbidden.

ERROR

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/file")
@Service
public class FileService {
 .....
    @CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:8080", allowCredentials = "true")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getFile/{fileId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getFile(@PathVariable(value = "fileId") String fileId) {
         ....
    }
}
```

But if I'm not using the path variable, it works.

SUCCESS

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/file")
@Service
public class FileService {
 .....
    @CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:8080", allowCredentials = "true")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getFile(@RequestBody String jsonFileId) {
         ....
    }
}
```

I'm calling this from javascript, below is the javascript request method.
url example

```
 http://localhost:8088/file/getFile/PUML1pZvusTlfBnlW3 
 fdjElEw8O7iVXfj801GyFF7fWeqyvPzwf1GB9lwha3T9GOoq2KEDaqf01l
 3DMRYInV9yHAMfd5_W4vY0S7d0SS9qk
```

and the request method

```
 $.ajax({
           
            url:url,
            type:"POST",
            data:data,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json;",
            crossDomain:true,
            cache:false,
            async:true,
            success:success,
            timeout:30000,
            error:function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);                
             
            }   
                
        }
    });
```

the javascript error :

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at

'http://localhost:8088/file/getFile/PUML1pZvusTlf....
from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS 
policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control 
check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the 
requested resource.
```

I know I can do without the path variable, but using the path variable is more efficient in my case.
So is there any solution of this issue ? Thanks

Comment: please post what your requests looks like, because this has most likely nothing to do with the "path variable" also please include full spring security debug logs

Comment: @Toerktumlare I already update my question, I'm calling from javascript ajax. If not because of the path variable?, why if i'm not using the path variable it works?

Comment: You have gotten your answer. Because of a missing header, thats why i wanted to see the full requests. Just to point out, when someome asks for the request we are not asking for the ”code that generates the request” we are asking for the actual request which ypu can for instance find in the network tab in the developer tools of your fav browser

Comment: @Toerktumlare Because your asking is quite ambigous, so I puth them both,

Comment: then i say request i mean something like this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST#example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using path variable there is no POST body and the browser is not sending application/json Content-Type header. You controller endpoint is not matched and the server does not respond with Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to a preflight request. Try sending some value in the POST body.